# Retrive IQ Data from Fake Backend in Qiskit

Tags: openpulse, qiskit

Is it possible to retrieve IQ data from Fake Backends in Qiskit?

I'm trying with the following code, but even by setting `meas_level=1`, I get only count vectors.

```python
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer  
from qiskit.providers.fake_provider import FakeAlmaden

backend_fake = FakeAlmaden()

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)  
qc.h(0)  
qc.cx(0, 1)  
qc.measure_active()  
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')

job = execute(qc, backend_fake, shots=10, meas_level=1, meas_return="single")   
result = job.result()
```

I need the IQ data to test a different discriminator from the default one.

Any suggestion?